# How to make a reasonable date after time

Tags: php

I am making a web app and I need to display the time when something was sent. Now, I want it to start like "2:30 PM", and then after the day has passed it would change to "July 26", how could I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not PHP - but I use the [timeago jquery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to accomplish this. This way, you store and retrieve one date and time, but it is displayed accordingly as time passes.

Answer (score 4):

The code is the same as you'd describe the flow in English: "if the time is less than a day ago, show 2:30PM, otherwise show July 26".

```
if (time() - strtotime($time_sent) < 24*60*60) {
    echo date('g:i A', strtotime($time_sent));
} else {
    echo date('F j', strtotime($time_sent));
}
```